# Xamarin auto generated AppResources.Designer.cs does not take subfolder name in ResourceManager baseName

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am working on iOS + Android project in Xamarin **(not xamarin-forms)**.
The app needs to support multiple languages and localization is working correctly using AppResources files.

For clean code setup and better management, `AppResources` files are stored inside  **Resx** directory within core project base directory.

On updating `AppResources.resx` file, Xamarin automatically recreates 
 `AppResources.Designer.cs` file in the same directory in which `ResourceManager` is created with base name **ProjectName.AppResources**

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ProjectName.AppResources", typeof(AppResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

However, since all app resources are stored under Resx folder, i'd like `ResourceManager` to be created with base name **ProjectName.Resx.AppResources**

What changes shuld i make sure AppResources.Designer.cs file creation takes into account the correct folder / namespace path?

Comment: Although i've found answer to my own question, i'm not closing the question as the answer could be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue reported on [Xamarin bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30044).

Fixed this by changing the Resource Id of resource files from `ProjectName.Rexx.AppResources.resources` to `ProjectName.AppResources.resources` in the files properties pane.